# What is the general procedure to create an AI system that can detect fire in images?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, ai-design, keras, image-recognition

I have no experience with any kind of AI, but I really want to develop a system that can detect fire in images. I think I will need a labelled dataset with labels "fire" or "not fire", but I am not sure how I should proceed and which steps I need to take to develop this system.

So, what is the general procedure to create an AI system that can detect fire in images?

I heard about the Keras library, which could allow us to do this. How could I do this with Keras?

Comment: What do you know about programming? How do you get an image on your comnputer?  What operating system does it run ? What image format (PNG, JPEG, ...)?  What books did you read about computer vision ? Wh See also http://refpersys.org/ ....

Answer (score 1):

Many AI libraries allow the ability to feed them an Image, but others have to be modified to allow this.

Disregarding the information above, as it is just a notification, you can do this in many ways. Depending on the library you use, different methods give varying accuracy results.

The real questions are:

1. How complex do you want the NN to be?
2. Is this going to be commercial, or private?

For any of the answers above, you will have to find the best method that works for your needs. The more this matters to the world, the more complex it will have to be.